# Releasing Memory taken by variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, memory-management

I am having fun creating my own wallpaper changer program. I know there are plenty on the internet, but i am simply trying to learn new stuff. So, till now, every time i was creating any simple program, i didn't care about RAM/Memory cuz i was mostly creating programs for school, and it was like one time use program, and then i was forgetting about it.

But now i am trying to create application i would like to use, something mine. I noticed my program takes around ~4000k in "alt + ctrl + del" window, and it takes sometimes up to 200,000k when it changes wallpaper, and sometimes goes down, and sometimes stays that high till it changes it to another one. 
[image: Memorytaken]

So here comes the question, what are tips to make my app use least possible ram while running (tray icon, and main windows is hidden using `if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState) Hide();`)

Is variable inside a function taking any memory? Example

```
int function(int a){ 
int b = 0;
int c = a+b;
return c;
}
```

Or are these variables released after function returns some value?

I could use some tips, guides, and/or links to articles where i could get some info about that. Newbie friendly tho.

EDIT:
Okay, i have read some, started to dispose bitmaps, got rid of one of my global variables i was using.. and its on steady 4000-7000k now. Raising a little when changing wallpaper, but then lowering back to that. So i guess thats kind of success for me. One more thing left. I downloaded kinda big/large/with many options program, that changes wallpapers, and it got a loot more options than mine, and still it takes around 1000-2000k, so ima read now what can take so "much" ram in mine. Right when i run my program its about 4100, so i guess i still can do something to optimize that. Thanks everyone for answers tho! :)

Comment: memory space for local variables on the stack is reclaimed when the stack is unwound when the method returns, references of local variables on the heap at that point become eligible for garbage collection. I'd google "C# garbage collection managed" as a starting point.

Comment: FYI, please don't prefix your titles with stuff like "Visual Studio C#". That's what the tags are for.

Comment: up: Roger that. Sorry, wont do that again. BrokenGlass: Thanks, for sure will read some about that

Comment: There's a 105% chance that you're forgetting to dispose the `Bitmap` objects that you're creating inside of methods. Wrap their creation in a `using` statement, or explicitly call the `Dispose` method on the object.

Comment: Yup, you are right, i wasnt disposing bitmaps.. well i am reading some stuff about memory and c#, and i will try to do my best to make it right. Hope i will learn some meantime. Thanks all for answers!

Comment: The "stack" of a program is pre-allocated, it can expand beyond the 1MB it starts with, but that memory never gets freed, so unwinding the stack itself won't lower memory usage.  Unrooting reference variables on the stack, will reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory from your program's perspective is divided in two blocks if you will. The Stack and the Heap.

The Stack represents the current frame of execution (for instance the currently executing function), and it is used to pass function parameters, return values and is where local variables are generally stored. That memory is purged when the the current frame of execution ends (for example your function exiting).

The Heap represents a memory pool where objects can be created and stored for longer periods of time. Generally, anything created using the "new" operator will go on the Heap, with the references existing on the Stack (for local context). If references to the allocated object stop being used, that memory remains taken until the Garbage Collector runs at some unspecified time in the future and frees the memory. When the GC runs can not be guaranteed - it might be when your program is running out of memory, or at scheduled intervals etc.

I think in the memory behaviour you are observing, spikes are due to opening up and loading resources, troughs are after the GC runs. Another way to observe this is to look at a program's memory footprint when there is UI showing on the screen, and when the program is minimized. When minimized the memory footprint will shrink, because all the graphical elements are no longer necessary. When you maximize the UI and redraw it, memory usage peaks.

You can look at the following articles for a better understanding of Stack and Heap:

[C# Stack and Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

[What are stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

You might also want to look into Garbage Collection:

[Garbage collection article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

... and [Value vs Reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use Using blocks around anything that implements the iDisposable interface.  Particularly if you are reading files, any streams, or any requests.  You can read a bit more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx and it gives a few examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Memory taken for locally declared variables will be automatically released.

Memory taken for variables that will persist outside the function will be released too, when they are no longer used, by something called the GarbageCollector (GC for short).

So don't worry, you're not creating a memory leak with your example function.

It's difficult to tell you where that 200,000l could be used up. There are profilers which can help (I have none to recommend, but this one comes first on Google: http://memprofiler.com/)

Comment: Indeed, the example function is probably optimized away by the jitter.